# Incorrect error throw order inside of console.log?

Tags: javascript

The code here is an extremely simplified version of what I am actually doing so please don't try to search for any deep meaning in this. I define a custom error like this.

```
function CustomError(message) {
  this.message = message;
  this.stack = (new Error()).stack;
}
CustomError.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);
```

Next, I create a simple function with only one purpose and that is to throw this error.

```
function foo() {
  throw new CustomError('custom error message');
}
```

Now I create a next function that will enter an infinite loop, checking for any errors, breaking as soon as any error, except for the custom one, is caught (well, it should but doesn't).

```
function bar() {
  for (;;) {
    try {
      console.lg(foo());
    } catch (error) {
      if (error instanceof CustomError) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        throw new Error(error);
      }
    }
  }
}

bar();
```

There is an intentional error in spelling of `console.lg(foo());` which should throw an error that is not an instance of `CustomError`, causing the `throw new Error(error);` line to be reached that would lead to the crash of the program.

Instead, the `foo()` function inside of `console.lg(foo());` is executed and `CustomError` is thrown, and the loop continues forever.

There is a chance that I am just making a silly mistake here but I don't see where. So my questions are:
Why is the interior of `console.lg();` reached without breaking the program when it is clearly not a valid code? And why is the `CustomError` thrown prior to the 'not a valid method' error?

Comment: You'll want to use just `throw error;` instead of `throw new Error(error)` for rethrowing the error.

Comment: inside `try` change `console.lg(foo());` to `console.log(foo());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how function calls work [as specified](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-evaluatedirectcall). `console.lg` will be evaluated to `undefined`. But then the arguments will be evaluated *before* it is checked whether the invoked value is actually a callable function. If the evaluation of the arguments already throws an exception (like your `foo()` does), that step doesn't even happen.

Answer (score 0):

With the interpreter, arguments are evaluated before their outer function is (attempted to be) called with said arguments. It won't look at the validity of an outer function call before resolving its arguments' function calls to values first.